# STL algorithm doesn't find iterator_category( )

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, xcode5

I'm trying to build pvr, an open source volume renderer for the Production Volume Rendering book (github [here](https://github.com/pvrbook), for reference).

Using OS X Mavericks and LLVM 5.0, I keep getting the following error on algorithm.h:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/algorithm:1834:90:
>   error: no type named 'iterator_category' in
>   'std::__1::iterator_traits
>
> > ::iterator>'
> >             *VSTD::*_fill(__first, __last, _*value*, typename iterator_traits<_ForwardIterator>::iterator_category());

The error refers to this section of algorithm.h:

```
template <class _ForwardIterator, class _Tp>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
void
fill(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, const _Tp& __value_)
{
    _VSTD::__fill(__first, __last, __value_, typename iterator_traits<_ForwardIterator>::iterator_category());
}
```

And I don't think I fully understand what's going on. I've tried adding

```
#include <iterator>
```

in the client code, but nothing changed.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The code you are posting looks correct. However, it seems to be used with an iterator which doesn't have a specialization of `std::iterator_traits<...>`.

Comment: I assume you read the read me and applied the required source patch for OSX (I can only assume it is still applicable to Mavericks).

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, the patch has been applied to pyports.h of the python currently being used (2.6.9, installed with homebrew). Still on the readme file, trying to build with scons instead of cmake+xcode, results in the same iterator errors plus another few new ones complaining of implicit instantiation of undefined template on std::string.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the result of incorrect specifying iterators. You should check how you call std::fill

Comment: I concur, but the point is the OP *doesn't* call `fill()`, the library source he downloaded *does*.